# Adding an alias to .bash_profile removes other commands?

Tags: macos, mac, command-line, terminal.app

Before touching .bash_profile:

`mongod` launches a mongo server, `rabbitmq-server` launches a rabbit server, etc.

But once I add:

`alias ethertunes="sudo NODE_ENV=development nodemon --debug ~/ethertunes/src/cluster/launcher.js"`

all my other commands are gone. (Still have `ls` and `CD` and such though...)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Are your other aliases and such defined in ~/.profile? If so, that'll be overridden by ~/.bash_profile, so everything in .profile becomes unavailable.  Solution: merge them; put all your definitions into a single profile file, rather than having them split between two files.  It doesn't really matter which name you use (.profile or .bash_profile) unless you have commands that depend on bash extensions -- in that case use .bash_profile.

Another possibility is that your old definitions were in .bash_profile, and when you added the new command you replaced (rather than adding to) the old contents.  In this case, you have to either look for a backup or set about recreating whatever you had in there.

Comment: In fact, it's good form to put most of your customizations in ~/.bashrc and have ~/.bash_profile run ~/.bashrc. Then they'll apply to login and non-login shells. ~/.bash_profile should contain things that are really intended only for login shells.